# Java java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date in russian locale only with maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to parse a string containing a month name using java. I created a test project in Idea using console application template and ran the following code:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
            String monthName = "апреля";
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", new Locale("ru")).parse(monthName);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
        } catch(Exception exc){
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, the output is the following:

```
11.0.1
4
```

But after I added maven support to the project, the output became like this:

```
11.0.1
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "апреля"
```

As far as I understand this has something to do with java versions, as in the old version (before 8) it was able to parse only this string: "апрель". I tried it and the output was as expected (with maven).

The question is how to get rid of the Unparseable date exception?

I tried with the following pom.xml versions:
1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-dates</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-dates</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>11</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

`mvn -v` output:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: How many Java versions do you have installed on your system?

Comment: When you have trouble parsing text, reverse the operation to generate text instead, so you can see what the parser expects. You're trying to parse `апреля`, but when formatting I get `апрель` on Java 15.

Comment: Using the newer Time API, I get `апреля`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Month` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Java version is a good thought, but since you have been able to parse in Java 11.0.1, Java version is hardly the explanation alone.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I have 2 versions: 11.0.1 and 16. In Idea I set up the 11.0.1 and JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1, MAVEN_HOME=C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.1, the same paths with \bin I added to the Path variable. Initially maven was using jdk-16 with the same result.

Comment: The two different pom's does the same, namely tell the _compiler_ invoked by Maven to behave as for Java 11.  The mechanism to choose the JVM at _runtime_ is different (and typically outside Maven realm).  I would suggest you write out all environment variables and system properties when running your program to verify that they are as expected.  I still suspect you hit a Java 8 (perhaps the one running IntelliJ)